# SQL Server Cancel Execution in SSMS vs Kill (SPID)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What is the difference between cancel execution in SSMS and using kill(spid).  In testing, I've discovered that when you cancel an execution, using kill (spid) with statusonly returns the error that the rollback operation is not in progress.

It's probably applicable to all recent versions of SQL Server, but in my case I'm using 2017.  SSMS is V18.

Comment: KILL kills the connection itself, not just the command. You won't be able to execute any other command with that connection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Technically it kills the session, not the connection, but in normal cases that's the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KILL` will rollback a transaction, cancelling the execution of a command will stop the query at the soonest opportunity and will not automatically roll it back.